# How does pandas qcut() method select what bins to put extra items in?

Tags: python, algorithm, binning

I would like to understand how `pd.qcut()` selects where to put extra items when `numItems % binSize != 0`. For example, I wrote this code to check how 0-9 items are binned in a decile setting

```
for i in range(10):
    a = pd.qcut(pd.Series(range(i+10)),10,False).value_counts().ix[range(10)].tolist()
    a = [x-1 for x in a]
    print(str(i),'extra:',a)

0 extra: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 extra: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 extra: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
3 extra: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
4 extra: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
5 extra: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
6 extra: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
7 extra: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
8 extra: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
9 extra: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Of course, this will change as `numItems` and `binSize` changes. Do you have any insight on how the algorithm works to try to select where to put the extra items? It appears that it tries to balance them in some way

Comment: "Quantile-based discretization function. Discretize variable into equal-sized buckets based on rank or based on sample quantiles. For example 1000 values for 10 quantiles would produce a Categorical object indicating quantile membership for each data point." - from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

Comment: Yes, but 1000 values for 10 quantiles means equal-sized 100 points per bucket. What happens when there are 1005 values for 10 quantiles? How does the algo choose which bins have length 101 and which have length 100?

Comment: You can read the [paper](http://robotics.stanford.edu/users/sahami/papers-dir/disc.pdf) on which the algorithm is based for the details.

Comment: The documentation link provided by @BurhanKhalid also includes a [link to the source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L142-L209) for `pandas.qcut`.

Comment: Thank you for the links, this is very helpful